# How to retrieve and/or add database table values and display in the textfield

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

#### computeHandler.java

```
public class computeHandler extends DBCollection
{
    private int totalcapitalPrice, totalprice;
    
    public void setTotalCapitalPrice(int temp)
    {
        this.totalcapitalPrice = temp;
    }
    public void setTotalPrice(int temp)
    {
        this.totalprice = temp;
    }
    
    public int getTotalCapitalPrice()
    {
        return this.totalcapitalPrice;
    }
    public int getTotalPrice()
    {
        return this.totalprice;
    }
}
```

where do I put the

`SELECT SUM(Capital_Price) FROM item_list`

and

`SELECT SUM(Price) FROM item_list`

I have a class named `DBCollection` which extends `DBConnection` and connects my codes to my database...

#### DBCollection.java

```
public class DBCollection extends DBConnection{
private Connection connect = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private Statement stmt = null;

public DBCollection()
{
    try
    {
        connect = super.getConnection();
        stmt = connect.createStatement();
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connected!");
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not Connected!");
    }
}

private void closeConnection()
{
    super.closeConnection(connect);
    super.closeRecordSet(rs);
    super.closeStatement(stmt);
}
```

I want to sum up all of the saved Capital_Price and Price values in my database.. and retrieve it to capitalPriceTF (textfield) and priceTF (textfield also).. how do I do that?

I also want to retrieve the First_name of the saved user... and display it to the Welcome(first name of user)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your query using `Statement` object:

So from `statement` object :

```
stmt = connect.createStatement();
```

Execute Your queries like this :

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(Capital_Price) sum FROM item_list");
```

`ResultSet` rs object holds the retrieved data from by that query, so you can get the data like:

```
int sum = rs.getInt("sum");
```

Then what all you have to do, just organize your code based on the above and you will get every thing works just fine.

Comment: should I create a method name?? like 

public void compute()
{
stmt = connect.createStatement();

rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(Capital_Price) FROM item_list");

String sum = rs.getInt(columnName);
} 

???

Comment: You could put it in the constructor after performing the connection.

Comment: public computeHandler computeCapitalPrice()
    {
        computeHandler CH = new computeHandler();
        String query = null;
        
        try
        {
            stmt = connect.createStatement();
            query = "SELECT SUM(Capital_Price) FROM item_list";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            rs.next();
            int sum = rs.getInt("Capital_Price");
            CH.setTotalCapitalPrice(sum);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
        }
        return CH;
    }

is this right???

Comment: @ianneAB Try it, then tell me what have you tried it you got another problem :)

Comment: In my jframe form.. i added event which is `formWindowOpened` and coded `DBCollection dbc = new DBCollection(); capitalPriceTF.setText(dbc.computeCapitalPrice().getTotalCapitalPrice());`

and it returns an error `int cannot be converted to String`

how do I resolve that?

Comment: try `capitalPriceTF.setText(String.valueOf(dbc.computeCapitalPrice().getTotalCapitalPrice()));`

Comment: now I can run the program.. but when I move in the window that should retrieve and display the capital price.. it gives me an error `Column 'Capital_Price' not found.. i've checked my database and the code i entered.. and the Capital_Price was right..

Comment: Give it an alias then use it, see the example above.

Comment: like String capPrice = String.valueOf(dbc.computeCapitalPrice().getTotalCapital‌​Price());
        capitalPriceTF.setText(alias);

tried it.. but it displays the same error Capital_Price not found.

Comment: Oh no i didn't meant that, i meant that make an alias for the SUM(Capital_Price) like: `rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(Capital_Price) sum FROM item_list");` then get it like: `int sum = rs.getInt("sum");`

Comment: thanks.. i'll do that also for my price.. but how about for retrieving the first name of the user in the database??

Comment: how can I retrieve the first name of the user who logged-in??

Comment: am I going to do what ive done in capital price?? like this 
public users userGreetName()
    {
        users users = new users();
        String query = null;
        
        try
        {
            stmt = connect.createStatement();
            query = "SELECT First_Name FROM user_information;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            rs.next();
            users.setGreetName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            
        }
        return users;
    }

but what would be the condition in my query??

Comment: and how am i going to call it again in my 'formWindowOpened' ?

Comment: I think you should do something like that `query = "SELECT First_Name FROM user_information WHERE USER_ID = 1"`, 1 is an example, you have to get the id or any one single info to create your condition with.

Comment: but how if the user that logged in has the id of 2 or 3.. how can i get their First_Name? if i do the WHERE condition ID to 1?

Comment: Oh am i have to explain every single thing, just add the variable to your query not a static number -> `query = "SELECT First_Name FROM user_information WHERE USER_ID = "+ userID +""`.